# C strings deletion in C++

Tags: c++, c, string

What's good and what's wrong? In which case do I have to call delete in order to prevent memory leak?
Also, is the behaviour exactly the same in C and C++? Are there any differences?

```
const char* a = "blahblah";
...
delete a;

char b* = new char('a');
...
delete b;

char c[100] = "blahblah";
...
delete c;

char d* = new char[40];
...
delete d;

char e* = new char[40];
...
delete[] e;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of your C++ book

Comment: Doesn't come from a book, was just wondering...

Comment: [My point is that _you_ should be coming from a book.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: Can't read lol :^) (this is ironic (yes it is (very (much))))

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> In which case do I have to call delete in order to prevent memory leak

Only `delete` what you got from `new` and `delete []` what you got from `new []`. Every other delete is wrong.

Comment: Could the downvoter please provide some insight ? I'm just a beginner so I could have made some silly mistakes / assumptions. Would really appreciate it :-)

Comment: (Beginner? Really? Mr 70.7k-rep C++ gold badge)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I don't really know much C++. I seriously think most of the C++ rep was from mistagged questions :-/

Comment: I downvoted your answer because it implies that using `new` and `delete` yourself is correct, which it is not.

Comment: @DeadMG You're right, a client should never use `new`. I think I read about it sometime.. can you provide a link ?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'm pretty serious, when reading C++ code I have frequent "does that even compile?" moments.

Comment: @DeadMG: You downvoted a perfectly accurate answer because of a loose inference? That's poor.

Comment: @cnicutar: Bah, broken system!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It is. SO rep says nothing about technical expertise.

Comment: There's nothing "loose" here. For the answer to be correct, it must be that if the OP follows his advice, he will get a correct program. That is not true with this answer, since it's basically impossible for the OP to actually perform this task without the aid of the compiler. Therefore, the answer cannot be correct, because the OP cannot create a correct program from this advice.

Comment: @DeadMG: It's nonsensical to suggest that you cannot create a correct C++ program if you write `new` and `delete`. The OP cannot use these basic keywords "without the aid of the compiler"? Are you on drugs?

Answer (score 3):

The rules are simple:

- Do not `delete` any pointer for which you did not call `new`
- Use `delete[]` for everything that you allocated with `new[]`
- Use `delete` (no brackets) for everything that you allocated with `new` (no brackets)

By following these rules you can see that only the deletions of `b` and `e` are valid:

- `a` and `c` have not been allocated with a `new`
- `d` needs a `delete[]`
- `b` and `e` are correct.

Answer (score 3):

They're all wrong. Do not ever call `delete` in a C++ program (unless you are directly implementing a memory-managing primitive, like smart pointer)- always use a smart pointer to handle resource destruction. For arrays, use a container like `std::vector<T>`. For strings, there is a dedicated `std::string` class. Finally, there are no primitive situations except `new` that create objects suitable for `delete`, whether directly or correctly (through a smart pointer), so if you did not use `new` or call a function that explicitly returns such (which should really return a smart pointer...), then you're definitely doing it wrong.

1. Wrong because there's no dynamic memory to delete.
2. Wrong because you should use smart pointer (`unique_ptr` looks fine here).
3. Same as 1.
4. Wrong because you need `std::vector` for dynamically allocated arrays.
5. Same as 4.

Comment: I am pretty certain that this is a learning exercise to spot intolerable "wrongs" that tend to crash your program, as opposed to "tolerable" ones, when you know that your program is bad, but it does not crash (i.e. the most common variety of programs out there).

Comment: I agree with this more than with that http://stackoverflow.com/a/15011082/1582182 .

Comment: What do you mean by "user mode"? I assume you do not mean user mode vs. kernel mode? ;)

Comment: And we're back to this again. This answer is just as dangerous as the last one where you wrote "do not ever call `delete`" and then left the qualifying comments in technical-speak. If you wrote "do not ever call `new` or `delete`" then it would be safer, but you can't.

Comment: @hyde: I guess he means outside of a library, in the space where you do your "actual" programming. For example, the smart pointer implementations are "allowed" to use `delete` and then, because those exist, _you_ do not need to... unless you're writing one of those implementations.

Comment: I have explicitly stated "Use a smart pointer to handle resource destruction.". What more do you want me to write? It is more correct than the other answer, which is "PLEASE DOUBLE DELETE MY BUFFERS".

Comment: @DeadMG: None of the answers says that.

Comment: There are plenty of cases for calling delete in an application "business" code, for example when the pointer is "owned" by library code, which may also delete it (an example is Qt and it's various classes where object commonly has a parent). And saying that using such a library is wrong is a bit strong statement.

Comment: @hyde: Even if you get an object back from a Qt function that Qt wants you to delete, there is no excuse for not immediately placing it in a smart pointer.

Comment: @DeadMG But that's just it, you don't get a parented object "back", you just have it there, and then can also just `delete` it in the *rare* cases where you want it gone before its parent (virtual destructor will take care of cleanup), and putting it to smart pointer first just makes no sense. Anyway, my point is, saying "never call delete in application code" is demonstrateably wrong. But I do agree it's something to be avoided, when not mandated by external factors like library design.

Comment: They're not all wrong. Some are but while the others are no longer  good practice, that's NOT the same as being definitively wrong.

Answer (score 2):

> Also, is the behaviour exactly the same in C and C++? Are there any differences?

There is no `delete` in C, nor does C have `new`. Only `free`, which corresponds with `malloc`.

Answer (score 2):

Three rules to follow:

1. `new` goes with `delete`;
2. `new[]` goes with `delete[]`;
3. If you want to write safe, robust, idiomatic code in 2013 and beyond, *use smart pointer implementations* (the result of which is that you will use `new` in your smart pointer constructor arguments, and then *not* use `delete`).

Answer (score 1):

Rule is that if you `new/new[]` then you have to use corresponding `delete/delete[]`.

Answer (score 1):

```
delete b;
delete[] e;
```

These are the only correct deletions.

As a rule of thumb:

- for each `new` there should be a corresponding `delete`
- for each `new … []` there should be a corresponding `delete []`

These rules don't take exception-handling into consideration. To keep your code exception safe, use smart pointers. And use `std::string` when you mean "string".