# delete memory automatically allocated by assignment of a literal

Tags: c++

```
char *str = "hi";

delete [] str;
```

I wonder why we can't free memory by delete operator? I'm getting an [exception](http://ideone.com/uE6Uss) 'Runtime error', when doing this.

`char *str = "hi";` automatically allocates memory and writes string in it.
So delete operator should work, or am I wrong with this assumption?

Comment: There is no (dynamic) memory allocation - str is just a pointer to a string literal.

Comment: Your title suggests you want to ask about deleting memory allocated by the new operator. Your question doesn't involve the new operator. So what are you asking?

Comment: @PaulR In the most general sense, there is (static and automatic allocation specifically), just not dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: @PaulR I have voted to reopen this question, because it's expressing a very commonly misconception how c++ works with such things. The answers may also be well suited to help others on research. Please provide appropriate duplicates, before closing this!

Comment: Many duplicates, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15011015/c-strings-deletion-in-c

Comment: @PaulR May be the question should have been to put on hold as a dupe in 1st place then. (to be honest: I tried to close vote as the 1st reaction as well, but found myself out of close votes for today. Thus I decided to write the answer and edit the OP)

Comment: Probably - finding duplicates can be hard work though, even when you know there are plenty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I wonder why we can't free memory by delete operator?

You don't need to in this case!

> `char *str = "hi";` automatically allocates memory and writes string in it.

No it doesn't! This all happens at compile time (and should even leave you a warning).
You didn't allocate `str`, you assigned a pointer to a `const char*` literal (the compiler is allowed to place wherever the implementation wants to), thus you can't delete it.

Dynamic allocation as managed with `new()` and `delete` would mean something like

```
char* str = new char[3];
strncpy(str,"hi",3);

// ...
delete [] str;
```

Answer (score 1):

The key thing to note from your question is

> > `char *str = "hi";` **automatically allocates memory** and writes string in it

String literals are automatically allocated **and** automatically deallocated. You can't free the memory yourself.

Note that they will last for the lifetime of the program, not just the scope of the variable. See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9505236/1313439).

Answer (score 1):

`delete` is used to de-allocate objects originally allocated with `new`. `delete[]` is used to de-allocate arrays originally allocated with `new[]`.

You didn't use `new` in your first line, so shouldn't use `delete` in the second.

Specifically,

```
char *str = "hi";
```

allocates memory for a *pointer* called `str`, which has automatic lifetime. Automatic here means the compiler takes care of it for you.

The pointer points to a string literal, `"hi"`, which was statically allocated once, at compile time, and can never be changed. In fact, your pointer should be const.

Now, if we change your code to

```
std::string str = "hi";
```

a dynamic allocation *does* happen since `std::string` makes a copy of your string literal, but it also takes care of releasing that copy for you. It may well use `new[]` and `delete[]` internally.

Answer (score 0):

That is a fair question. But there's more to the business of constant strings than meets the eye: the compiler and linker are free to maintain pools of read-only literals wherever they want.

In fact, if the `str` in your example is in automatic (function-local, stack) storage and you have a high-speed memory pool handler, you may be able to make a catastrophic mess by trying to free it and then reuse it.  (Don't try this at home  :-)